# Node.js Express Server doesn't work on a different server, but works on my machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I run my node.js server on my machine, it works perfectly fine. However, when I ssh into a machine I got from digital ocean, it throws this error. I used flightplan to move my files to the machine.

```
deploy@myserver:~/node-app/bin$ node www

/home/deploy/node-app-1479873242669/routes/index.js:76
                        [newValue]: {
                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/deploy/node-app-1479873242669/app.js:36:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

This is the code concerning the error:

```
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                newValue = 0;
                console.log("queuer val " + newValue);
                fbRef.update({
                    [newValue]: {
                        [UID]: ID
                    }
                });
            }
```

And like I said, this works perfectly fine on my machine. Thanks!

Comment: Your droplet probably has an older version of node installed that doesn't support that ES6 syntax. You can check with `node -v`. The first version of node that supported this particular syntax was node v4.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update node to latest version :

```
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get -y install nodejs
```

Should work after that.

Answer (score 1):

Creating object with computed keys is a part of [ES2015 Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)(ES6). See [Object Initializer spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer).

in your case, vanilla JavaScript doesn't support this:

```
[newValue]: {
    [UID]: ID
}
```

So probably your `node -v` will be something above `v6.0.0`, but the other server will be an older version. Either **update node version** or use [**`babel-node`**](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) with presets.